# Ajax AutoComplete Scrolling Issue

Tags: asp.net, ajax, styling, autocompleteextender

in ajax web site there is an example about AutoComplete (there is [link](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx)) and its quite good with slider. And here is the codes:

```
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender 
    runat="server" 
    ID="autoComplete1" 
    TargetControlID="myTextBox"
    ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
    ServicePath="AutoComplete.asmx"
    MinimumPrefixLength="2" 
    CompletionInterval="1000"
    EnableCaching="true"
    CompletionSetCount="20" 
    CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement" 
    CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem" 
    CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem"
    DelimiterCharacters=";, :"
    ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">
        <Animations>
            <OnShow> ... </OnShow>
            <OnHide> ... </OnHide>
        </Animations>
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

But when I try to use its codes I am getting such kind of results (no slider and bad view)

[image: my problem]

what is missing in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Css Height, Min-Height or Max-Height in the Css class according to your need.
It will add scroll bar on right side of your list. Width can also be used to control width.

Don't forget to set overflow: auto;